# C#, Finding 2 columns sum together in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am bit new to linq .

How do I get the total sum of two columns in my data table.

Let say 2 columns are A& B . I want **numeric** sum of entire column A and entire column B
 (i.e totalSum= sum(A)+sum(B))

**IMP :**
If I have any field in either of 2 columns a non numeric field (eg AB,WH,DBNULL) . That field should be considered as zero while summing up the values so that it wont throw any exception.

Comment: This will answer your question 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432281/get-sum-of-two-columns-in-one-linq-query

Comment: @Bobby that link wont address my non numeric field issue

Answer (score 4):

For each row or the sum of entire column A and entire column B?

In the first case you could do a select:

```
var resultWithSum = from row in table
select new{ 
  A = row.A, //optional
  B = row.B, //optional
  sum = row.A + row.B
}
```

Otherwise you can do:

```
  result = table.Sum(row => row.A + row.B)
```

Comment: @Nithesh: This won't compile if the +-operator is not defined for the datatypes of A or B.

Comment: Your syntax is off on your anonymous type declaration.

Comment: @ aL3891 i was referring to 2nd case.

Comment: ah, yes, i wrote that from memory, i fixed it now

Comment: @NitheshHebri yes, that is true. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum.aspx) are the types you're allowed to return