# LINQ group by and SUM

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, entity-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get sum of two columns in one LINQ query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432281/get-sum-of-two-columns-in-one-linq-query)

I need to know how to write an LINQ Query that will give me the same results as this SQL Query 
:

```
select sum(col1) as [col1] , sum(col2) as [col2] , sum(col1)/sum(col2) as [col3], col4 as [col4] 
from some_table 
group by col4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full props go to [Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264697/steven) for this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2432348/211627

```
from row in some_table
group row by row.col4 into g
select new
{
    col1 = g.Sum(x => x.col1), 
    col2 = g.Sum(x => x.col2),
    col3 = g.Sum(x => x.col1) / g.Sum(x => x.col2),
    col4 = g.Key
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Or with Lambda, i am assuming `some_table` is an Entity or Repository .. etc.

```
some_table.GroupBy( row => row.col4).Select( row => new
{
    col1 = row.Sum(x => x.col1), 
    col2 = row.Sum(x => x.col2),
    col3 = row.Sum(x => x.col1) / row.Sum(x => x.col2),
    col4 = row.Key
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is assuming that your table is some sort of entity. This will put it into an `Anonymous Type`, but can be used to create an object of your own type also.

```
myInitialCollection.GroupBy(x => x.Col4).Select(x => 
    new { 
            col1 = x.Sum(y => y.Col1), 
            col2 = x.Sum(y => y.Col2), 
            col3 = (x.Sum(y => y.col1) / x.Sum(y => y.col2)), 
            col4 = x.Key
    });
```