# Custom OrderBy in jLinq

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible in jLinq to sort my data according to a defined function?

I would like to have something like:

```
var res = jLinq.from(data).orderBy(function (r) { return r.x + r.y; }).select();
```

Currently I have implemented this solution

```
var index = function (r) { return r.x + r.y; };

var res = jLinq.from(data).select();
res.sort(function(a,b){ return index(a)<=index(b) ? 1 : -1; });
```

but I was wondering if it is feasible in jLinq before the select

Answer (score 2):

This library provides what you are looking for
http://linqjs.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could add a computed column to your query and sort by that. Take a look at this post: [Get sum of two columns in one LINQ query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432281/get-sum-of-two-columns-in-one-linq-query)

Comment: In order to apply your solution it is necessery to map my object into "obj + index". I don't know if it is possible to do it in jLinq and however this sounds like a workaround.. does it means that there is no way to do it in a more direct (and elegant) way?